# Install PHP 7.4 through IUS Package Manager on CentOS 7

Tags: server, centos7, package-managers, php-7.4

I am new to server configuration so please help me with this. I have a server with **CentOS Linux 7.4.1708** installed on it. I have **Webtatic** package manager which does not have the **PHP 7.4**. There is not much on internet regarding it, if webtatic is active or dead. I can either update to **Remi** or **IUS**. Since IUS has better security our company is inclined towards IUS. I am trying to look at https://ius.io but couldn't find documentation to install it.

I want to remove webtatic package manager and PHP 7.1. Install **IUS** and **PHP 7.4**.

Please help me to install this tech stack. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should explain what "better security" means, especially as IUS pulls work from Fedora which pulls work from Remi... which pulls work from Upstream (php.net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to update to latest **CentOS 7.9.2009** to have all expected updates, including lot of security ones.

- **webtatic** seems indeed dead, no activity since October 2019
- **IUS** seems a bit asleep nowadays (see their wishlist... missing extensions, and some outdated versions)
- **Remi** is the most active

Then you have to disable webtatic, by removing the webtatic-release configuration package.

For "Remi", simply follow the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/), using "single version", it should take care of the upgrade from webtatic packages

Comment: thanks for your solution. I used the Remi wizard instructions and was able to install Remi and update PHP 7.4. Once everything was working then I removed webtatic package manager.